# OCaml counter does not terminate without using threads

Tags: multithreading, functional-programming, ocaml, counter

I have the following code:

```
let counter n = 
    let rec count i = 
    if i > n 
      then ()
      else 
          print_int i; 
          count (i+1)
    in count 0
```

It should simply output all numbers from 0 to n. To clarify, I know there are easier ways to achieve the same result but I want to know why it is not working in this specific case. 
When I run this code with some parameter eg. `counter 5` it does not terminate.

Instead when I change the last line of my code `in count 0` to `in Thread.create count 0` it outputs `012345`

Can someone explain this behaviour?

**EDIT**

Also found that if you modify the code to this:

```
let counter n = 
    let rec count i = 
    if i > n 
      then ()
      else 
          let i = i
          in print_int i; 
          count (i+1)
    in count 0
```

it works fine. Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your indentation is misleading; your code does

```
if i > n then () else print_int i;
```

first and then

```
count (i+1)
```

Of course it doesn't terminate! What you want is

```
else begin
  print_int i; 
  count (i+1)
end
```

(or `else ( ... )`). See e.g. "Using begin ... end" in https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/if_statements_loops_and_recursion.html.

Comment: Ah okay, that explains alot. But why does it work when when using a thread?

Comment: Could you maybe check my edit in the original question? I am not that experienced with OCaml but I really want to understand what is going on

Comment: It "works" with thread since the main thread exits the function `counter` while the newly created thread keeps running infinitely calling `count (i+1)`.  But the code is still wrong since your intention should not be to have an infinite loop.